# how to send an array from controller to view to show it codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am new to codeigniter I have a simple query in model like this below :

```
    function showbook(){
            $number_test =10;
            $this->db->select('qid, question, q_type');
            $this->db->from('qbank');
            $this->db->where('q_type',2);
            $this->db->limit($number_test);
            $query = $this->db-> get();
            return ($query->result());

    }
```

so in my controller I want to store query result into a variable and send to view and use it in that and this is my controller :

```
public function show(){

        $this->load->model('add_book_model');
         $data['stuff'] = $this->add_book_model->showbook();
        foreach ($data as $row)
{
    $question[] = $row->question;
    // echo $row->question;

}
$this->load->view('desktop/view_book',$question);

    }
```

and finally this is the part of my view that I want to echo results. I want to know that is that correct to process data in model save them in variable in controller and send them to view I mean is it the true meaning of MVC in code ignite? If yes what is my mistake?

```
<?php
    print_r ($question[]);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model use return `result_array` instead of `result`

```
function showbook(){
        $number_test =10;
        $this->db->select('qid, question, q_type');
        $this->db->from('qbank');
        $this->db->where('q_type',2);
        $this->db->limit($number_test);
        $query = $this->db-> get();
        return ($query->result_array());
}
```

In your controller

```
   $this->load->model('add_book_model');
   $data['stuff'] = $this->add_book_model->showbook();
   $this->load->view('desktop/view_book',$data);
}
```

Finally in the view:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($stuff)) {
    foreach ($stuff as $single_stuff) {
        print_r ( $single_stuff['question'] );
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In model try this

```
function showbook(){
        $number_test =10;
        $this->db->select('qid, question, q_type');
        $this->db->from('qbank');
        $this->db->where('q_type',2);
        $this->db->limit($number_test);
        $query = $this->db-> get();
        return $query->result();
}
```

In controller

```
$this->load->model('add_book_model');
   $data['result'] = $this->add_book_model->showbook();
   $this->load->view('desktop/view_book',$data);
}
```

Now in view you can access result array using foreach loop

```
foreach($result as $row){

    echo $row->qid;
    echo $row->question;
    echo $row->q_type;

    }
```

If you are echoing value in html try like this

```
<table>

<th>qid</th>
<th>question</th>
<th>question type</th>

foreach($result as $row){
<td><?php echo $row->qid; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->question; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row->q-type; ?></td>

        }

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
in controller

```
public function show(){

    $this->load->model('add_book_model');
    $data['stuff'] = $this->add_book_model->showbook();        
    $this->load->view('desktop/view_book',$data);
}
```

and in your view

```
foreach($stuff as $value){
  echo $value->question;
}
```